# How to update the text of a button from inside a GridViewAdapter in Android both of which are on the same activity?

Tags: android, gridview

I have an activity in which there are 2 columns. The left column has a button displaying a dynamic integer. This dynamic integer is printed on this button as follows:

```
button.setText(GlobalVariables.getInstance().GetMyArrayList().size());
```

On the right hand column I have a GridView which is using a GridViewAdapter to inflate the layout. I have a separate "GridViewAdapter.java" file to inflate the layout. Therefore, I now have 2 Java files - One is my activity file and another is this GridViewAdapter file.

Inside this GridViewAdapter I have (for each grid element) 1 ImageView, 1 TextView and 1 Button which the ViewHolder is maintaining for me. The button which I am using here inside this Adapter also has an OnClickEventListener to handle the onClick method. On pressing this button I call a setter function which is globally accessible and pass some value to it as follows:

```
GlobalVariables.getInstance().SetMyArrayList(someValue);
```

Now my question begins. The moment I press the button which is present inside the GridView, my button with a Dynamic Integer (which is on the left hand column outside) should increment its value. But I cannot increment it as I cannot access this button from inside the GridViewAdapter. Should I have an option to access that dynamic button from inside the GridViewAdapter, I will simply write the code:

```
button.setText(GlobalVariables.getInstance().GetMyArrayList().size());
```

which will refresh this button and an updated value will be reflected over that button. Can anyone please help me out with this? I want to update the text on a button from inside a GridViewAdapter where the GridView and the Button both are present on the same activity but there are 2 separate java files - one for the activity and one for the GridViewAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Make `GridViewAdapter` an inner class of your activity class. Then it will have access to all fields of container class.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I will try the same and will share the results!